# How to hide mapview (google maps v2) when fragment changed

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

My project have 2 fragment (2 tabs), contain MapView on each. When I change from tab1 to tab2 then hide  MapView1 and show MapView2 (right case) but MapView1 not hide, it still showing, although I use MapView1.setVisible(View.GONE). How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed it.

```
 @Override
   protected void onPause() 
   {
        parentLayout.removeView(mapView);
        super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() 
   {
        if (mapView.getParent()!=parentLayout)
            parentLayout.addView(mapView);
        super.onResume();
   }
```